# Deserialize JSON String Nested Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, restsharp

I am trying to use [Riot games REST API](http://developer.riotgames.com/api/methods) to make a webapp in C#.  I am fine with making the requests using [RESTSharp](http://restsharp.org/) but am having some problems using [JSON.Net](https://json.codeplex.com/) to convert the returned Json to an object.  My request returns a JSON string for example:

`{\"dyrus\":{\"id\":4136713,\"name\":\"Dyrus\",\"profileIconId\":23,\"summonerLevel\":1,\"revisionDate\":1376908220000}}`

I want to deserialize this into an object that has attributes: `id`, `name`, `profileIconID`, `summonerLevel` and `revisionDate`.

The problem I am having is that the information is being deserialized as a string because the Dictionary is nested.  What is the best way to just retrieve the nested Dictionary portion of the string: `{\"id\":4136713,\"name\":\"Dyrus\",\"profileIconId\":23,\"summonerLevel\":1,\"revisionDate\":1376908220000}` and convert it into an object?

Thanks for your help!

Edit:

Here is what I have tried:

```
public class LeagueUser
{
    public LeagueUser(string json)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string jsonString = (string)serializer.DeserializeObject(json);
        LeagueUser test = (LeagueUser)serializer.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
    }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public long revisionDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you have a look at the examples here: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html

Comment: Yes I have.  I have deserialized it no problem into a string but do not know how to get right to the inner dictionary.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that you have tried.

Comment: Is your JSON actually escaped like that (double serialized), or is that just what is showing in the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the constructor, change `LeagueUser` class to this

```
public class LeagueUser
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public long revisionDate { get; set; }
}
```

and use [Json.NET](https://json.codeplex.com/) to deserialize the json into a `Dictionary<string, LeagueUser>`

```
string jsonStr = "{\"dyrus\":{\"id\":4136713,\"name\":\"Dyrus\",\"profileIconId\":23,\"summonerLevel\":1,\"revisionDate\":1376908220000}}";

var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, LeagueUser>>(jsonStr);
```

You can get the `LeagueUser` object this way

```
LeagueUser leagueUser = deserializedObject["dyrus"];
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked!  I know I need to mark this as the answer but don't see where I do that.  As soon as I find it I will!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want by creating custom converter for your `LeagueUser` class:

```
public class LeagueUserConverter : JsonConverter
{

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(LeagueUser) == objectType;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (!CanConvert(objectType)) return null;

        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        var user = new LeagueUser
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt64(jObject["dyrus"]["id"]),
                Name = jObject["dyrus"]["name"].ToString(),
                ProfileIconId = Convert.ToInt32(jObject["dyrus"]["profileIconId"]),
                SummonerLevel = Convert.ToInt32(jObject["dyrus"]["summonerLevel"]),
                RevisionDate = Convert.ToInt64(jObject["dyrus"]["revisionDate"])
            };

        return user;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Next you need to decorate your class with the defined converter:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(LeagueUserConverter))]
public class LeagueUser
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ProfileIconId { get; set; }

    public int SummonerLevel { get; set; }

    public long RevisionDate { get; set; }
}
```

And wherever you need call `DeserializeObject` method:

```
var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LeagueUser>(json);
```

where the `json` variable is the json string you posted in your question.